# How to do I find a joint density?

Tags: joint-distribution

Can someone please help me with finding the joint density of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ when $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2=X_1-X_2$?

Comment: The general procedure is illustrated in the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32620/dividing-a-uniform-by-a-normal-random-variable-whats-the-distribution.

Comment: Do you know anything about the distributions of X1 & X2?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $\hat{Y}_1 = \displaystyle \frac{X_1+X_2}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\hat{Y}_2 = \displaystyle \frac{X_1-X_2}{\sqrt{2}}$ are the coordinates of the *random point* $(X_1,X_2)$ measured with respect to *axes* that are rotated through an angle 
of $\pi/4$, and so it must be that $f_{\hat{Y}_1,\hat{Y}_2}(y_1, y_2)$ 
is just the joint density
$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)$ with respect to the rotated axes. Now scale the random
variables $\hat{Y}_1$ and $\hat{Y}_2$
by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ to get the joint density of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It may also be worth noting the relationship between joint characteristic functions:

$\phi_{Y_1,Y_2}\left(t_1,t_2 \right)= \mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\left(t_1Y_1+t_2Y_2\right)} \right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\left[\left(t_1+t_2\right)X_1+\left(t_1-t_2\right)X_2 \right] }\right] = \phi_{X_1,X_2}\left(t_1+t_2,t_1-t_2 \right).$